# API monitor for android?

Tags: android, security

I strongly suspect my mom's smartphone has malware on it. It replaces the lock screen and opens an invalid URL every couple of hours (I don't have the name on-hand). I've downloaded malwarebytes and Avast antivirus, neither have found the culprit. The list of installed Apps is fairly short and ordinary.

I'm not an expert, but I was wondering if there was a way to know which apps have certain "intents" registered such as Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON or Intent.ACTION_VIEW, and know when they're listening for or sending them out. Any software to help me accomplish this?

Comment: I recommend backing up any important data, and factory resetting the phone. It'll save you a lot of trouble.

Comment: Try andro guard.